# In Windows 7 Ultimate, how do I enable multiple rows of icons in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I moved my taskbar to the right side of my screen, now vertically oriented. If I have too many applications running to show in a single row in the taskbar, the overflow is placed in a second row but I must use the scroll arrows to access them. Multiple rows are fine, I understand that part, but I don't want to use the scroll arrows. Is there a way to just enable multiple rows of icons in the taskbar?

This was never an issue before because my taskbar was horizontal and I had more space to fill up. Never had the scrollbars before.

Comment: This appears to be an oversight on Microsofts side. When the taskbar is horizontal you can add multiple rows by simply dragging it up. When the taskbar is vertical though, dragging it just seems to stretch it out but not add additional rows. There may be a registry tweak to fix this, but I am not aware of one.

Comment: Amazing how 10 years later this is still an issue in Windows 10...

Answer (score 3):

I have Windows 7 also, and tried moving my taskbar to the right side of the screen like you said, and then opened a whole bunch of programs...you're right, i can make the taskbar wider, but which just makes the actual icons wider also...but it won't display two rows of icons...I know from experience that if there is no easy way to do this in the Windows configuration, then it is not possible without a hack or program tweak...sorry...*it does work on the bottom, and the top also...*

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/887856-narrowthin-vertical-taskbar-in-windows-7/page__gopid__592467816&#entry592467816) is a workaround for you problem.

Comment: I don't think it solves original problem (about too much RUNNING applications), but it was useful to me.