# Multi-column Taskbar When It's on Left/Right in Windows

Tags: windows, taskbar, desktop-customization

When the Windows Taskbar is at bottom/top (horizontal) it can be multi-row, but when you put it on left/right side of screen (vertical), it only has one column (row!).

Is there a way to have two columns Taskbar on left/right?

I have Windows 10.

A multi-row taskbar in horizontal mode (on Windows 7):
[image: A multi-row taskbar in horizontal mode (on Windows 7)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Windows 7 Ultimate, how do I enable multiple rows of icons in the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/184502/in-windows-7-ultimate-how-do-i-enable-multiple-rows-of-icons-in-the-taskbar)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem, and based on that question it seems there is no solution for this problem. So I don't know if I should hit "That solved my problem!" button or not!

Comment: maybe you should wait for some time to see if anybody else has a solution, because that's for windows 7 and I'm not sure if there's a workaround in windows 10

Comment: @Rahmani ever find a workaround for Windows 10?

Comment: Nope @CeePlusPlus